# How to Capture and Convert Iframe Content into Multiple PDF Pages Using Java Libraries?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pdf, iframe, pdfbox

I'm currently working on a Java project where I need to capture the content of an extensive iframe from a web page and convert it into a PDF file. The content of the iframe is too long to fit on a single PDF page, so I need a solution that can automatically divide this content across multiple pages in the PDF.

I've tried using Selenium with Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP) to capture the iframe content and convert it into PDF. However, I'm encountering an issue where the Page.printToPDF command captures the entire web page including elements outside the iframe, leading to formatting issues.

```
String caminhoDriver = "C:\\Drivers navegadores\\CHROME120.exe";
String caminhoDownloadPdf = "C:\\Drivers navegadores\\test.pdf";
String ipNavegador = "127.0.0.1:9223";
boolean landscape = false;
String colorMode = "RGB";
String pageSize = "A4";
String header = "Cabeçalho da Página";
String footer = "Rodapé da Página";
int scale = 1;
int marginBottom = 0;
double marginLeft = 0;
int marginRight = 0;
int marginTop = 0;
double opacity = 0.5;
int fontSize = 12;
String textAlign = "left";
int borderWidth = 1;
String pageRanges = "1-3";



codigoPonto = 1;
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", caminhoDriver);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", ipNavegador);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#conteudo")));

codigoPonto = 2;
Map<String, Object> commandParams = new HashMap<>();
commandParams.put("landscape",landscape);
commandParams.put("colorMode", colorMode);
commandParams.put("pageSize", pageSize);
commandParams.put("header", header);
commandParams.put("footer", footer);

codigoPonto = 3;
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
params.put("scale", scale);
params.put("marginBottom", marginBottom);
params.put("marginLeft", marginLeft);
params.put("marginRight", marginRight);
params.put("marginTop", marginTop);
params.put("opacity", opacity);
params.put("fontSize", fontSize);
params.put("textAlign", textAlign);
params.put("borderWidth", borderWidth);
if (!Objects.equals(pageRanges, "todas")){
    commandParams.put("pageRanges", pageRanges);
}

codigoPonto = 4;
Map<String, Object> response = (Map<String, Object>) driver.executeCdpCommand("Page.printToPDF", commandParams);

codigoPonto = 5;
byte[] pdf = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode((String) response.get("data"));
java.nio.file.Files.write(java.nio.file.Paths.get(caminhoDownloadPdf), pdf);
```

I'm considering using other Java libraries for this task and would like some recommendations. Here are my specific questions:

1. Are there any Java libraries that can capture web content
   (specifically an iframe's content) and convert it into a PDF,
   handling the pagination for extensive content?
2. If I were to capture the content as an image or in another format
   first, could libraries like Apache PDFBox or iText be used to
   convert this content into a paginated PDF? How would I handle the
   pagination in such a case?

Any advice or code examples would be greatly appreciated, especially if someone has faced and solved a similar challenge.